# Please help me solve average problems

Tags: statistics

The least and greatest numbers in a list of 7 real
numbers are 2 and 20, respectively. The median of the
list is 6, and the number 3 occurs most often in the list.
Which of the following could be the average (arithmetic
mean) of the numbers in the list?

I. 7
II. 8.5
III. 10

(A) I only
(B) I and II only
(C) I and III only
(D) II and III only
(E) I, II, and III

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  There is an expectation at this site that when you post a question that you explain its source, include any work you have done on the problem, and explain where you are stuck so that we can write a response appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 1):

Your list consists of 
$$2,3,3,6,X,Y,20$$
with unknowns $X,Y$. They are bounded by
$$6 < X < Y < 20$$
and thus the mean $m$ is bounded by
$$\frac{2+3+3+6+6+6+20}{7} < m < \frac{2+3+3+6+20+20+20}{7}$$
or
$$6.57 < m < 10.57 \ ,$$

so your answer is (E).

Comment: $7$ **real** numbers!!!

Comment: @barakmanos So? Please tell me where my answer contradicts this assumption? A real number $x \in (6,20)$ is bounded by $6 < x < 20$ just like I used it ...

Comment: It doesn't contradict this fact, but it simply doesn't take (infinitely) many other options into consideration.

Comment: @barakmanos That's why there is such a wide possible range for the mean: Because there are so many possibilities. I'd like to know how you'd find any tighter bounds or any other further restrictions than I already did?